# NullPointer when trying to addMarker with custom icon

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm able to add a marker onto my map fragment if I don't add a custom icon to the marker. I can change the color of the marker and the application will run fine.

Here's the marker snippet:

```
 BitmapDescriptor icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_navigation_black_24dp);
 lat = 37.476696;
 lng = -122.195791;
 markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
         .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
         .title("You")
         .icon(icon);
 Marker driverMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
 markers.add(driverMarker);
```

I create and add the marker inside getMapAsync in onMapReady.

Here's the error log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at maps.f.g.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.af.g$a.<init>(Unknown Source)
at maps.af.g.a(Unknown Source)
at maps.af.R.<init>(Unknown Source)
at maps.af.t.a(Unknown Source)
at vl.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:167)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.addMarker(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)
at com.sample.app.fragment.CustomerFragment$1.onMapReady(CustomerFragment.java:135)
```

Where line 35 is

```
Marker driverMarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

I've checked if markerOptions and googleMap is not null and they're not null. So I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Are you sure `icon` isn't null?

Comment: Yes `icon` is not null too. And the drawable exists inside my drawable folder. I've also tried to load a png file which is in my drawable folder, and that works. But I can't load vector assets i.e. ic_navigation_black_24dp.xml which are found in the Vestor Asset Studio.

Comment: If you can repro this bug, and do it in a version that hasn't been ProGuarded, it would be much easier to debug.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually existing related issues in gmaps-api-issues tracker, [Issue 7696](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7696) and 
[Issue 9011](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9011), which are not totally fixed yet according to the thread.

However, you may also check the given workaround and see if it's applicable on your end. I hope it works.